# How insert content of TXT file to JSON file

Tags: php, json

I want import the "links" from a links.txt file and put it on a JSON file but the result is like:

```
{"domain":[ "www.google.es","www.yahoo.com","www.example.com"],
 "id":6
},
{"domain":["www.google.es","www.yahoo.com","www.example.com"],
 "id":6
},
{"domain":["www.google.es","www.yahoo.com","www.example.com"],
 "id":6
}
```

Expected:

```
{"domain":"www.google.es","id":6},
{"domain":"www.yahoo.com"],"id":7},
{"domain":["www.example.com"],"id":8}
```

As you can see, the id is the same at I want differents id and the links are added 3 times the 3 links and I want add 1 link on 1 option.

```
<?php
$jsonContents = file_get_contents('data/data.json');
$data = json_decode($jsonContents, true);
$fp = 'links.txt';
$last_item = end($data);
$last_item_id = $last_item['id'];
$contents_arr = file($fp,FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
foreach($contents_arr as $key=>$value) {
    $contents_arr[$key] = rtrim($value, "\r");
    $data[] = array(
        'domain' => $contents_arr,
        'id' => $last_item_id+1,

    );
}
$json = json_encode($data);
file_put_contents('data/data.json', $json);
```

Comment: The IDs are probably the same because the objects are the same. Is this import a one time thing? Else you can just throw away all duplicates in a text editor and import the way you normally would.

Comment: `$last_item_id` never changes. Replace `$last_item_id+1` to `++$last_item_id`

Comment: @u_mulder geat, the items ID its solved now, now I've the biggest problem of the script, the array thanks you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$last_item_id+1 returns $last_item_id+1, it does not change $last_item_id variable.

Dont change $contents_arr array used for loop inside the loop.

You use for domain $contents_arr, which contains all values. Create for domain new array, ie:

```
foreach($contents_arr as $key=>$value) {
    $data[] = array(
        'domain' => [rtrim($value, "\r")],
        'id' => ++$last_item_id,
    );
}
```

Comment: It worked thanks you very much! 6 min and I accept it as answer